# InvalidAuthenticityToken after using Jquery File Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ember.js, jquery-file-upload

I have a Rails 4.0 app with an Ember.js frontend. I'm using Ember-Auth in conjunction with Devise to handle authentication. For the most part, everything works. However, if I use Jquery File Upload, then all subsequent queries to the server result in an InvalidAuthenticityToken error. The file upload itself works perfectly, but if for instance I visit the Organizations index page afterwards, I'll get the error. If I reload the page, then the errors stop coming and everything works fine again until I perform another upload.

The uploader looks like this:

```
didInsertElement: ->
  $('#image_upload').fileupload
    url: "/images"
    formData: [{ name: 'auth_token', value: Whistlr.Auth.get('authToken') }]
    success: (response) =>
      @get('parentView').get('controller').set('image_token', response.token)
```

Even if I remove everything but the url, I get the InvalidAuthenticityToken afterwards. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the csrf token. Try use this in formData: [
    { name: 'authenticity_token', value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
  ]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick. I've also tried attaching the authenticity_token to all ajax transactions by following [these instructions](http://blog.waymondo.com/2012-12-18-ember-dot-js-and-rails-authentication-gotchas/), but the problem persists. Any advice would be appreciated! I've opened a bounty on the issue.

Comment: Reading over [the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures), it looks like the authenticity_token is specific to each session. Perhaps the error is happening because the session is somehow getting reset during the Jquery File Upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my suspicion that the session was getting reset, I tried passing the authenticity_token back the client side from the server. Surely enough, it was changing. So I manually placed the new authenticity_token in the headers. The code looks like this:

```
def create
  image = Image.create(image_params)
  render json: {image: image, authenticity_token: form_authenticity_token}, status: 201
end

$('#image_upload').fileupload
  url: "/images"
  dataType: "json"
  formData: [{ name: 'auth_token', value: Whistlr.Auth.get('authToken') }]
  success: (response) =>
    @get('parentView').get('controller').set('image_token', response.image.token)
    $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', response.authenticity_token)
```

Note the last line of the javascript, which replaces the csrf-token. Thankfully, this works. As far as I can tell, it's also secure. (If you see a security flaw, please let me know!) But it still seems weird that this is necessary. Nowhere else in my app do I have to manually replace the csrf-token. Why is this happening here? Is it because the session is getting reset, and if so, why is that happening here but not elsewhere?